# Does ` std::binary_search` sort the array first or it assumes we have sorted it?

Tags: c++, std, binary-search

If I created an array in C++ that I know for sure is sorted, can I just use `std::binary_search` and it will be faster than linear search or it will sort the array first and slower than linear search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It assumes that the given array is sorted.